# PyQt display fullscreen image

Tags: python, pyqt, screenshot, fullscreen

I'm using PyQt to capture my screen with QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()) and I was wondering if there was a way I could display my screengrab fullscreen (no window borders, etc.) I'm trying to find a way to desaturate my display with PyQt

Comment: I've come across the PyQt QWidget showFullScreen function, but the window it's in still has padding that I can't get rid of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint to the QWidget constructor in symphony with self.showFullScreen() in the image widget's code achieves this.

Answer (score 0):

A *PyQt6* working example of the solution as described by *directedition*.

- `Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint` produces a borderless window, [doc](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType).
  **Notice** that it can be either passed as `flags` argument in the constructor or fixed in a second moment with `setWindowFlags`
- `showFullScreen()` shows the widget in full-screen mode, [doc](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#showFullScreen)

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Img(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, img_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.qimg = QImage(img_path)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint) 

    def paintEvent(self, qpaint_event):
        # event handler of QWidget triggered when, for ex, painting on the widget’s background.
        painter = QPainter(self)
        rect = qpaint_event.rect() # Returns the rectangle that needs to be updated
        painter.drawImage(rect, self.qimg)
        self.showFullScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    img_path = # add path of the image

    window = Img(img_path)
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```